# Intermittent PyDev crash "java was started but returned exit code=1" when running/auto-saving

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) on Windows 10 crashes intermittently with "java was started but returned exit code=1" when attempting to run/auto save a PyDev/Python program. Restarting Eclipse and running the same program works. PyDev is version 8.0.1.202011071328.

[crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHHcL.jpg)

eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.800.v20200727-1323.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1300.v20200819-0940
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: What does `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\0racle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe" -version` return?

Comment: `C:\Users\Keith>"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -version
java version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)`

However, Eclipse hasn't crashed since downgrading to 2020-06 .